# Maximal number of missing entries in a bivariate table with relative frequencies

Tags: elementary-number-theory, statistics

Assumed I have a bivariate table of relative frequencies and consider the table including the marginal frequencies. What is the maximal number of entries which can be missing such that original table can be reconstructed?

The example below shows a 2x3 frequency table. The second table shows the table including the marginal frequencies. For such a 3x4 table can be up to seven entries missing and I'am able to reconstruct the base frequency table. The question is: What is the maximal number of missing entries (?) such that the base frequency table can be reconstructed?

| Base frequency table | y=0 | y=1 | y=2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **x=0** | 0.02 | 0.04 | 0.34 |
| **x=1** | 0.02 | 0.28 | 0.30 |

| Frequency table including marginals with missing entries | y=0 | y=1 | y=2 | $\sum$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **x=0** | 0.02 | 0.04 | ? | 0.40 |
| **x=1** | ? | ? | 0.30 | ? |
| $\sum$ | 0.04 | ? | ? | ? |

With a program distributing randomly ? in the second table and trying to reconstruct the base table, I get someting like

number of missing entries <= #rows + #columns + 2

#rows = number of rows from base table and #columns = number of columns from base table.